# Which is a better usage variant of linking boost library between single-header, static library and shared library?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-libraries, static-libraries, header-files

Boost provides 3 ways of linking their library: single-header, static library and shared library. Which is the preferred default? What are the pros/cons of using one approach over the other? I seem to prefer the single-header variant since it allows me to avoid the compilation step of a standalone library. And I don't need all the features all at once. I only plan on using Boost's Unit Test framework. Most set-up/getting-started documents always mention the quick and dirty method of using the single-header. This link http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/more/getting_started/windows.html describes "can be used in “header-only” or “separately compiled” mode, although separate compilation is recommended for serious use." - I wonder why serious-use requires compilation - or do we really need to compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Boost Libraries *require* compilation to be used in your project, and some Boost Libraries *require* compilation for specific features adjacent to them. So you *need* to compile Boost if you plan to use any of those libraries/features that require it.

As for choosing between a static and shared library, that's mostly down to personal preference. Generally speaking, when I use Boost, I don't anticipate a scenario where I'm going to pull an ABI-compatible-yet-newer version of Boost, and package that code without changes to my own code. So I pretty much always use Boost (or, more precisely, the portions of boost that require compilation) as static libraries.